# AWS Cognito Swift SDK How can I check if a user is confirmed?

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, authentication, amazon-cognito

I am very new to Cognito.  I have just successfully setup a signUp system using the examples provided and can use my iOS app to signUp users.

I require the users to verify an email during the signup.

Their data appears on the Cognito console and prior to selecting the link in the verification email, their status is unconfirmed.

In my app I don't want the user to be able to use the app until they verify their email.

How can I check when the user has clicked on the email confirmation?  I don't want to route the user back to the login page after they sign up.  I take them to a page where they can press continue after confirming their email.

I have tried the following:

```
self.user!.getSession(self.username, password: self.password, validationData: nil).continueWith(block: { (session) -> Any? in
    if (self.user!.confirmedStatus == AWSCognitoIdentityUserStatus.confirmed) {
        print("confirmed")
    } else if (self.user!.confirmedStatus == AWSCognitoIdentityUserStatus.unconfirmed) {
        print("unconfirmed")
    } else if (self.user!.confirmedStatus == AWSCognitoIdentityUserStatus.unknown) {
        print("unknown")
    } else {
        print("elsecase")
    }
    return nil
})
```

For some reason this is printing confirmed even though the user is unconfirmed.

Being very new to all this I'm really not sure what approach to take in my scenario to see when the user has clicked on their verification link.

Answer (score 1):

Use **userAttributes** array to get all user attributes including "**email_verified**" flag

In CognitoYourUserPoolSample Project the UserDetailsTableViewController class have a method named refresh(), this method is used to get user details after login. I have added few line of code to identify whether the user confirmed to email address or not.

```
  func refresh() {
    self.user?.getDetails().continueOnSuccessWith { (task) -> AnyObject? in
        DispatchQueue.main.async(execute: {
            self.response = task.result
            self.title = self.user?.username
            self.tableView.reloadData()

            // Get user attributes and check the "email_verified" flag
            let attributes = self.response?.userAttributes
            if let emailVerifiedAttribute = attributes?.filter({$0.name == "email_verified"}), emailVerifiedAttribute.count == 1  {
                if (emailVerifiedAttribute[0].value == "false") {
                    print("Email not verified")
                    self.openEmailVerificationVc()
                }else{
                    print("Email  verified")
                }

            }
        })


        return nil
    }
}
func openEmailVerificationVc(){

    user?.getAttributeVerificationCode("email")
    // Show email verification vc here,

}
```

From email verification view controller call "**verifyAttribute**" method

```
var user: AWSCognitoIdentityUser?
var pool: AWSCognitoIdentityUserPool?  

override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        self.pool = AWSCognitoIdentityUserPool(forKey: AWSCognitoUserPoolsSignInProviderKey)
        if (self.user == nil) {
            self.user = self.pool?.currentUser()
        }



    }
func verifyEmailWithCode(code:String){
    user?.verifyAttribute("email", code: code)
}
```

Comment: I get an error when I call getDetails: Error Domain=com.amazonaws.AWSCognitoIdentityProviderErrorDomain Code=-1000 "Either startCustomAuthentication or startPasswordAuthentication must be implemented on your AWSCognitoIdentityInteractiveAuthenticationDelegate" UserInfo={NSLocalizedDescription=Either startCustomAuthentication or startPasswordAuthentication must be implemented on your AWSCognitoIdentityInteractiveAuthenticationDelegate}

Comment: It could be an issue with UserPool setting in AWS console. Select required checkboxes in AWS Console-Userpools settings

Comment: Hey, cool. Thanks. Any suggestion on what checkboxes are required? I'm operating a bit in the blind since I don't have access to the AWS console for this project (our client does).

Answer (score 1):

You need to simply check this value on callback:

```
task.result?.userConfirmed?.boolValue
```

This will return true or false whether user is confirmed or not. Hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

As I mentioned above, I haven't had success with either `getDetails` or `getSession` for checking if a user has confirmed. What I'm doing instead is calling `AWSMobileClient.sharedInstance().signIn`.

If I get an error: `AWSMobileClientError.userNotConfirmed`, then I take this as indicating the user hasn't confirmed.

If I successfully get the user signed in, then I take this as indicating the user has confirmed.

Of course, this has the side effect of leaving the user signed in. I initially was trying to sign the user out after this as part of the `signIn` callback, but this has the odd side effect of having the `signIn` callback called twice!